# is Worksheetfunction still working, when automatic calculation is turned of?

Tags: excel, vba

As I'm using dynamic named ranges (which use the volatile `OFFSET`) i want to turn off `Application.Calculation` when running my sub in vba to accelerate the makro. Inside the code I'm using `Application.Match`. It seems like this is still working, but I'm not sure that this is always the case.

Comment: You could add a `Worksheet.Calculate`, before the `Application.Match` to be certain.

Comment: Should still work, you could also use `Evaluate` within your code.

Comment: @ Marco Getrost  I'm using `Application.Match` in a loop (I didn't mention that in the question), so adding `Worksheet.Calculate` before `Application.Match` would throw me back to the start.
@JvdV I will try that.